# Accessing ASP Web Application from selected computer only

Tags: asp-classic

I have a web application developed in asp classic which is running online. I want that application to be accessible through computers in my office only. Can this be possible?

Comment: It's a bit broad this question. You have multiple options... Secure the site and provide access only to specific individuals, use IP restrictions to only allow certain IPs to access the site *(this isn't full proof though, IPs can be spoofed)*. Is it possible?, absolutely!

Comment: Do you have a machine in your office network which you can use as a server - if you do then that would be the most logical approach?

Comment: @Lankymart With IP spoofing, won't the spoofed IP receive the traffic and not the attacker?

Comment: @pee2pee You are correct, still IP based authentication is [never a good thing](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/4538/76700).

Comment: Is the server also in your office? Or is the server publicly accessed?